# React can the callback function of useState increase performance?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance

With Callback

```js
  const [state, setState] = useState(() => {
    email: '',
    password: '',
  });

  const handleStateChange = useCallback((stateName) => (e) => {
    setState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [stateName]: e.target.value,
    }));
  }, []);
```

Without Callback

```js
const [state, setState] = useState(() => {
    email: '',
    password: '',
  });

  const handleStateChange = useCallback((stateName) => (e) => {
    setState({
      ...state,
      [stateName]: e.target.value,
    });
  }, [state]);
```

It's possible to use dispatch of `useState` without appending dependencies through the callback function.

I think it reduces dependencies so that helps for performance.

Is this correct?

In addition, sometimes, the callback argument doesn't get current state correctly. I don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: `useState` callback is mostly used when your next state depends on your previous state, as you receive `prevState` in the callback but I don't think it helps with performance. Do correct me if I'm wrong :)

Comment: Passing a callback to `setState` primarily increases correctness of your program, as it will work properly with batched updates. Performance is irrelevant here.

Comment: The callback that you are passing to `useCallback` doesn't actually depend on `stateName` - it's a parameter of the curried function, it's not a closed-over outer variable. So you shouldn't declare it as a dependency in either code.

Comment: "*I think it reduces dependencies so that helps for performance.*" - if you're unclear about performance, measure it. If you cannot measure a difference, it doesn't matter. In all likelihood, `useCallback` is not even needed here at all.

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped 'state' as a 'stateName' in the dependices. Thank you for the answers, guys

Comment: Measure it and find out?

Comment: Not yet, I just read comments. I'll try to find out

Answer (score 2):

There likely isn't a measurable difference between the two approaches (but you could try testing it!). This is extreme early optimization, and if you want to increase performance, you should focus on other parts of your app that can yield better results.

The difference between the two approaches is to solve different problems (getting the prevState vs not getting It). It calls the same logic internally, and React should be smart enough to not create a performance difference between the two.

Think of it this way: do you worry about adding an extra state or two because of performance? No, of course not, because it doesn't matter.